# onClick fetch data c# xml reader

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to have a button that on button1_click it opens an URL to fetch live exchange rates. i am a little unsure where to actually place the algorithm. so for this purpose can we assume its a blank windows form with a single button that upon clicking prints the fetched data next to the clicked button.This is what i have keep in mind im new to c# and visual studio changed a few things that made my initial code much more confusing to me any simplification helps.

```
public partial class eth: Form
{
    private const string InputUri = @"https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/ticker/ethusd";

    public eth()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        public static List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>> GetCurrencyListFromWeb(out DateTime currencyDate)
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>> returnList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>>();
            string date = string.Empty;
            currencyDate = NewMethod(returnList, ref date);
            returnList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("usd", 1));
            return returnList;
        }
    }

    private static DateTime NewMethod(List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>> returnList, ref string date)
    {
        DateTime currencyDate;
        using (XmlReader xmlr = XmlReader.Create(InputUri))
        {
            xmlr.ReadToFollowing("bid");
            while (xmlr.Read())
            {
                if (xmlr.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element) continue;
                if (xmlr.GetAttribute("timestamp") != null)
                {
                    date = xmlr.GetAttribute("timestamp");
                }
                else returnList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>(xmlr.GetAttribute("ask"), decimal.Parse(xmlr.GetAttribute("last_price"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
            }
            currencyDate = DateTime.Parse(date);
        }

        return currencyDate;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try my version.  See posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189562/how-do-i-skip-xml-reader-by-reading-empty-attribute-node#comment85460515_49189562

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is tested and working fine. You are calling a REST endpoint and it is returning a list of values as a json. I am using the HttpClient to call the endpoint and will need to add the other properties as needed from the documentation. One thing to be mindful is that the results change with the symbols provided. So, will need to provide that responsibility to another class. In fact, you should always move the external library calling to another class to comply with the SRP.

```
public partial class ExchangeRates : Form
{
    public ExchangeRates()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private const string InputUri = @"https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/ticker/ethusd";

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = await GetTicker();
        richTextBox1.AppendText($"mid: {result.Mid}\n");
        richTextBox1.AppendText($"bid: {result.Bid}\n");
        richTextBox1.AppendText($"ask: {result.Ask}");
    }

    private static async Task<Ticker> GetTicker()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(InputUri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ticker>(content);
            return output;
        }

        throw new Exception("Ticker exception.");
    }
}

public class Ticker
{
    [DataMember(Name = "mid")]
    public decimal Mid { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "bid")]
    public decimal Bid { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ask")]
    public decimal Ask { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

### Update 1

Sorry about the issue. I have used Newtonsoft.Json package here. We can use string manipulation also but it is a bit ugly. So, use the JArray from the package to convert the result to an array.

### Update 2

Ok, I scrapped the JArray part and went back to string splits.

### Update 3

Really sorry, I have used a different end point earlier. I have updated answer according to the required end point. Here you will have to use the JsonConvert class from the same Newtonsoft.Json package. I have also added DataMember attributes for easy deserialization. DataMember is part of System.Runtime.Serialization namespace.

### Update 4

Appended the results to a rich text box as you have requested. But, why do want them in a rich text box? These are read only data that you want to display to the users. I believe you should have different labels for each field and display them separately.

Comment: When compiled and ran on my end it says system.FormatException: input string was not in a correct format and highlights                
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await GetTicker();
    }

Comment: It now says JArray isnt in the namespace newtonsoft.json

Comment: Please add the package Newtonsoft.Json and the using as using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;. The package is Newtonsoft.Json but the namespace where the JArray is contained is Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.

Comment: Now when compiled and ran when i click the button that fetches the data it throws an error at    "private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await GetTicker();
    }" error reading jarray object is not an array

Comment: Interesting, because this is working for me fine. Anyway, I have added another update without JArray, and based on string splits. Try this.

Comment: it keeps highlighting the await getTicker portion when i run it and says input string was not in a correct format

Comment: that inputuri doesnt have labels for the values listed i was using https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/ticker/ethusd and calling on last_price and bid to show in the array

Comment: I have updated the answer according to the required endpoint. I have used an incorrect end point earlier. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Thank you i appreciate it it appears to be working now!

Comment: now how would i output the datamember portion to a textbox? i have the textbox created as richTextBox1 currently just dont understand quite how to call to those strings values without some sort of syntax error

Comment: Thank you! and i only said rich text box just in case i decide to add formatting later would a label be more functional in the code for just the plain text received?

Comment: Yes, I believe a label would be more appropriate in this context and you would be able to add basic formatting to labels.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The best option would be to post your questions on this site. There are a huge amount of professionals who will be able to answer your questions with the best answers.